# Hibernate: a foreign key has the wrong number of column. should be 1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to map to entities Report and ReportLookup:

```
@Entity
public class Report extends AbstractMigrationObject implements Serializable {
    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    private Long reportId;
    private String reportName;
    private String appName;
    private Integer reportNum;
    private String issue;
    @JsonProperty
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "reportName"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "appName"),
    })
    private Set<ReportLookup> lookupSet;

@Entity
public class ReportLookup implements Serializable {
    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    private Long reportLookupId;
    private String parameterName;
    private String attributeName;
    private String lookupName;
    private Integer sequence;
    private String labelOverride;
    private String defaultValue;
    private Integer required;
    private Integer hidden;
    private String reportName;
    private String operator;
    private Integer multiLookup;
    private Integer reportNum;
    private String appName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "appName", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "reportName", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Report report;
```

I don't know how to map composite foreign key. Always get this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [persistance-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering ru.ocrv.ekasui.changemonitoring.maximo.entity.report.Report from ru.ocrv.ekasui.changemonitoring.maximo.entity.report.ReportLookup has the wrong number of column. should be 1

Comment: Can you share your DB scheme for the two tables as well please?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you should try to change your @JoinColumns structure with the two Ids of your Class

```
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "reportId", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "reportLookupId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you can't add two columns with the same name, if you want to add a  `reportId` in `ReportLookup` Table and `ReportLookup` in the Report Table delete the second `@JoinColumn`, 
in `ReportLookup` :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "appName", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private Report report;
```

and in Report :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "reportName")
})
private Set<ReportLookup> lookupSet;
```

**Second Solution**
 you should add @JoinColumns in the principal entity

```
@JsonProperty
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "reportName"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "appName"),
})
private Set<ReportLookup> lookupSet;
```